# Proactive message using MS bot composer for Facebook Messenger

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm using Microsoft bot framework composer to send proactive messages. I tried testing in emulator it is working fine. Later I tried to test the same on Facebook it didn't work. Tried adding service URL as trusted but that didn't help me. Can I know if I'm following it properly or not. Thanks in advance.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ProActiveMessage(ProactiveConvRef proactiveConvRef)
    {
        try
        {
            bool anyPropNotNull = proactiveConvRef.GetType().GetProperties().Any(prop => prop.GetValue(proactiveConvRef) != null);
            if (anyPropNotNull)
            {
                var newReference = new ConversationReference()
                {
                    Bot = new ChannelAccount()
                    {
                        Id = proactiveConvRef.BotId
                    },
                    Conversation = new ConversationAccount()
                    {
                        Id = proactiveConvRef.ConversationId
                    },
                    ServiceUrl = proactiveConvRef.ServiceUrl,
                };
                
                await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(string.Empty, newReference, async (context, token) => await SendProactiveMessage(proactiveConvRef.BotMessage, context, token), default);
            }

            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = "Proactive messages have been sent.",
                ContentType = "text/html",
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
       
    }

    private async Task<string> SendProactiveMessage(string botMsg, ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var uri = new Uri(serviceUrl); // serviceUrl, I'm getting it from turn object
            var MicrosoftCreds = new MicrosoftAppCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx");
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(uri, MicrosoftCreds);
            AppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceUrl);

            var res = await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(botMsg), cancellationToken);
            return res.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

        

    }
```